# ASIHTTPFormRequest postBody is null

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to upload an image using ASIFormRequest as follows:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"pic"]);
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"Temp.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"image"];
request.delegate = self;
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The image is not being successfully uploaded, as I get an error message from the server, so I logged the request post body:

```
NSLog ("%@", [request postBody]);
```

However, the postbody is null - why would this be? I have checked that imageData is not empty.

Comment: Any error message logged from the delegate methods `- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;`? Do you need to setPostValue:forKey: for the request?

Comment: No error is logged. Using setData withFileName is the recommended method for appending image data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem is any re-direct on multi-part form data will dump the form data. Setting shouldUseRFC2616RedirectBehaviour to YES will not prevent the dumping for multi-part forms.